# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, excel, oop, google-sheets

I'm writing data, fetched from jobs API, to the Google spreadsheet. Following encoding for 'latin-1' encodes till page# 93 but when reaches 94, it goes in exception. I've used different following techniques, but 'latin-1' did max pagination. Else have been commented(as they die on page #65). Could you please tell me how to modify non-commented(i-e .encode('latin-1')) to get 199 pages safely written on spreadsheet?
Code is given as below:
Any guideline in this regard is appreciated in advance.

```
  def append_data(self,worksheet,row,start_row, start_col,end_col):
    r = start_row #last_empty_row(worksheet)
    j = 0
    i = start_col
    while (i <= end_col):
        try:
            worksheet.update_cell(r,i,unicode(row[j]).encode('latin-1','ignore'))
            #worksheet.update_cell(r,i,unicode(row[j]).decode('latin-1').encode("utf- 
             16"))
            #worksheet.update_cell(r,i,unicode(row[j]).encode('iso-8859-1'))
            #worksheet.update_cell(r,i,unicode(row[j]).encode('latin-1').decode("utf-
            8"))
            #worksheet.update_cell(r,i,unicode(row[j]).decode('utf-8'))
            #worksheet.update_cell(r,i,unicode(row[j]).encode('latin-1', 'replace'))
            #worksheet.update_cell(r,i,unicode(row[j]).encode(sys.stdout.encoding,  
            'replace'))
            #worksheet.update_cell(r,i,row[j].encode('utf8'))
            #worksheet.update_cell(r,i,filter(self.onlyascii(str(row[j]))))      

        except Exception as e:  
            self.ehandling_obj.error_handler(self.ehandling_obj.SPREADSHEET_ERROR,[1])
            try:
                worksheet.update_cell(r,i,'N/A')
            except Exception as ee:
                y = 23
        j = j + 1
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: What's in the problematic cell, and what does the traceback look like?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `unicode()` on a byte string value, which means Python will have to *decode* to Unicode first:

```
>>> unicode('\xea')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It is this decoding that fails, **not** the encoding from Unicode back to byte strings.

You either already have Latin-1 input data, or you should decode using the appropriate codec:

```
unicode(row[j], 'utf8').encode('latin1')
```

or using `str.decode()`:

```
row[j].decode('utf8').encode('latin1')
```

I picked UTF-8 as an example here, you didn't provide any detail about the input data or its possible encodings. You need to pick the right codec yourself here.

Comment: I fetch data from the page like this, actually I've to see a jobs as per user criteria. I get json array by implementing requests libraray of python. one page is share as a specimen:
https://api.angel.co/1/jobs

Comment: And what does `repr(row[j])` print for a row throwing the exception?

Comment: Thanks for guiding but the fact is, I've run all your three suggestions for encoding. None of these worked. All of them throw exception at page# 65.

Comment: The only one goes from page#65 successfully, what I'd already shared in post. This command:
worksheet.update_cell(r,i,unicode(row[j]).encode('latin-1','ignore'))

BUt t throws exception on page#94. Could you plz tell me what's going on?

Comment: I *don't know*, not without seeing the actual data you are trying to handle and the *full traceback* of the exception. Otherwise this is just a guessing game.

Comment: Bro last command worked for me and still not gave error. I show you the link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aj1jszqeNSOCdFNYazMtTi1qdno0MlBzbzItajlKLUE&usp=drive_web#gid=32

Comment: Each cell has u' in beginning and ends with ('). How to remove that?
Any idea dear?

Comment: @Rose: That just means it is a unicode literal *already*, you don't need to call `unicode()` on it in that case. All you need to do *then* is encode it. Unless `worksheet.update_cell()` takes Unicode already, in which case encoding would be the wrong thing to do, and possibly the cause of your exceptions.

Comment: but brother if i do so:
worksheet.update_cell(r,i,repr(row[j]))
I get NO exception.
When I simply write as:
worksheet.update_cell(r,i,row[j])
Exception is thrown!

Comment: Right, `repr()` is a *debugging tool*; I wanted you to tell me what was shown for that (including the `u` and quotes, because that is a clue for me) *for the row that would give you an exception*. So in your `except Exception` handler, I want you to add a line that'll tell you what `repr(row[j])` looks like when an exception is thrown. I'd also love to see the full traceback, the message shown when you do **not** catch the exception with a `try` / `except` handler.

Comment: I just wanna (u) from start and (') from end. For instance, see Company URL block. No url has hyperlink or blue color coz of these characters. How to remove?
This is the print:
No exception i got!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aj1jszqeNSOCdFNYazMtTi1qdno0MlBzbzItajlKLUE&usp=drive_web#gid=32

Comment: I cannot see that; that is a private document. I wanted you to use a `print` statement or similar, **not** add the `repr()` output to your worksheet. That's a needle in a haystack search I am not going to do. :-)

Comment: OK wait, I check without using repr() and then share exception print with you! :)

Comment: I just used this, with out repr(), as worksheet.update_cell(r,i,row[j])

UnicodeEncodeError: 
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 742: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Right; that is the [N-dash character](http://codepoints.net/U+2013) and cannot be encoded to Latin-1. What exactly is the library you are using for the worksheet object? We need to figure out what encodings it'll accept. Encoding is the right approach here and `unicode(...).encode('latin1', 'replace')` should just work but may not be the best choice.

Comment: librarires for spreadsheet what being used are:
import gdata
import gdata.spreadsheet.service
import gdata.docs.data
import gdata.docs.client
import gspread

Comment: I've a;ready checked this:
unicode(...).encode('latin1', 'replace')
It throws exception on page#94 :(

Comment: @Rose: and what exception does it throw? Full traceback?

Comment: @Rose: From what I can make out, you should be encoding to UTF-8. Most likely the exception you see is because you use Latin-1 instead. If you *do* get a traceback when using `unicode(...).encode('utf8')` then share the *full traceback* for that exception.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lead_gen/spreadsheet.py", line 143, in append_data
    worksheet.update_cell(r,i,unicode(row[j]).encode('utf8'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 423, in update_cell
    cell_elem.set('inputValue', unicode(val))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: couldn't i change following unicode to simple string:
u'2014-03-07T21:27:09Z' into 2014-03-07T21:27:09Z...???

Comment: @Rose: that error indicates that `update_cell` expects Unicode values; that means you should not be encoding at all. What happens if you use *just* `unicode(row[j])`, no encode?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lead_gen/spreadsheet.py", line 134, in append_data
    worksheet.update_cell(r,i,unicode(row[j]))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 426, in update_cell
    self.client.put_feed(uri, ElementTree.tostring(feed))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 742: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: This command throws no exception, else all throw!
Perfect one is:
worksheet.update_cell(r,i,repr(row[j]))

couldn't i change u'2014-03-07T21:27:09Z' into 2014-03-07T21:27:09Z...??? here

Comment: @Rose: that is because that's just ASCII text. In that case you are forced to use `unicode(row[j]).encode('ASCII', 'replace')` but that hardly seems the right solution. I am very surprised the GData libraries cannot handle Unicode properly.