# Python - Show exactly data from MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, django

Im using Django to develop my web service.
I have a database name is 'django_dulichdb' and have one table 'polls_dulich'. 
I had set CHARACTER SET utf8  and COLLATE utf8_general_ci, but still have diffrenent between data on database and data when it's got by python code. That's it

After typing `SHOW variables LIKE '%character_set%';`, this is my charset

```
> | Variable_name            | Value                      |
> +--------------------------+----------------------------+ | character_set_client     | latin1                     | |
> character_set_connection | latin1                     | |
> character_set_database   | utf8                       | |
> character_set_filesystem | binary                     | |
> character_set_results    | latin1                     | |
> character_set_server     | latin1                     | |
> character_set_system     | utf8                       |

| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

**1. In mysql, i type**

```
select * from polls_dulich
```

And result is true. Its display right Vietnamese

tp://travelhanoi.com.vn/Data/ResizeImage/~/userfiles/files/diem du lich ha noi/van_mieu_quoc_tu_giamx131x99x2.jpg | Ha Noi  | Văn Miếu, ban đầu là nơi học của các hoàng tử, sau mở rộng thu nhận cả các học trò giỏi trong thiên hạ. Văn Miếu Quốc Tử Giam ban đầu là nơi học của các hoàng tử, sau mở rộng thu nhận cả...

**2>In terminal, i type**

```
python select.py
```

to call select.py. That is select.py

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '1', 'django_dulichdb');
with con:
cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM polls_dulich")

    for i in range(cur.rowcount - 10):

        row = cur.fetchone()
        print (i+1),row[4]
```

And result is like that

2 ChÃ¹a cÃ³ qui hoáº¡ch tÆ°Æ¡ng Ä‘á»‘i gá»n gá»“m cá»•ng tam quan, phÆ°Æ¡ng Ä‘Ã¬nh, hai dÃ£y dáº£i vÅ© vÃ  nhÃ  thá» máº«u. CÃ¡c kiáº¿n trÃºc nÃ y tuy má»›i Ä‘Æ°á»£c trÃ¹ng tu vÃ o nÄƒm 1954 nhÆ°ng váº«n giá»¯ Ä‘Æ°á»£c tÃ­nh cá»• truyá»n trong...

I dont know why is that. Help me please. Thanks a lot :(

Comment: can you try doing row[4].encode('utf8')?

Comment: I trie with encode('utf8'), it return  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "select.py", line 16, in <module>
    print (i+1),row[4].encode('utf8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: refer to similar questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267629/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xea-in-position-8-ordinal

Comment: Thanks but its not working :(

Comment: what error did you get afterwards?
Can you try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365660/python-mysql-unicode-and-encoding

Comment: Thanks Rafael Barros so much. That link you send me is very helpful. Thank you!!!!!

Comment: is your issue fixed? if so, answer your own question.

Comment: yes. I fix it :D. I dont know why, just try many time and fix it at the end. My answer was posted in my question's edit yesterday. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Whowww, Its very simple :D. This is answer for anyone when get trouble like this Just modify select.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# code above for using utf8
import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys
reload(sys)
con = mdb.connect(host='localhost',
                     user='root',
                     passwd='1',
                     db='django_dulichdb',
                     charset='latin1',
                     use_unicode=False);
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM polls_dulich")
    for i in range(cur.rowcount - 10):     
        row = cur.fetchone()
        print (i+1),row[4]
```

:D. May help somebody.